# Randomizing embed thumbnail with gifs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have the thumbnail of an embed randomized with each time the command is sent

I've tried:

```
(url=f'{str(random.choice(list))}')

list=['https://tenor.com/view/rocket-league-im-fast-boi-zoom-gif-23504270', 'https://media.tenor.com/pw9ZsUdsEYgAAAAj/capoo-blue-cat.gifhttps://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gifhttps://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gif']
```

It sent the first one, but it the gif itself didn't show, so I then sent the command 2 more times and it only showed the second gif.

Comment: Try changing them like this; `https://media.tenor.com/OymJl7uYRLQAAAAi/rocket-league-im-fast-boi.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Check your List variable, currently it has 2 links, of which, 1 is invalid.
you have
`https://tenor.com/view/rocket-league-im-fast-boi-zoom-gif-23504270` and `https://media.tenor.com/pw9ZsUdsEYgAAAAj/capoo-blue-cat.gifhttps://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gifhttps://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gif'`

I think you mean

`list=['https://tenor.com/view/rocket-league-im-fast-boi-zoom-gif-23504270', 'https://media.tenor.com/pw9ZsUdsEYgAAAAj/capoo-blue-cat.gif', 'https://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gif', 'https://media.tenor.com/f8hUa09f_SoAAAAj/fortnite-fortnite-dance.gif']`
Let me know if this resolves your mistake, because currently we can only see a small part of your code.